# ¿Cómo puedo mandar la variable de sesión a la otra pagina?

Tags: php, mysql, android, session

estoy programando mi app para que con la id del usuario que se almacena en en la variable de sesión se puedan guardar datos en otra tabla, pero el problema es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable de sesión no pasa de una pagina a otra lo que me impide llamarle. Como le puedo hacer? será que tiene que ver con la interacción con el android studio?

codigo:

login.php

```
<?php
    include "bd.php";
    
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

    $query1 = "SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE user='$usuario' AND pass='$contraseña'";
    
    $ide = mysqli_query($conexion,$query1);
    $ide = $ide ->fetch_assoc();
    $id =$ide['id'];

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
    

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE user='$usuario' AND pass='$contraseña'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query2);
    

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
        
        echo "inicio correcto"; 
        
    }else{
 
        echo "no pudo ingresar";
    }
?>
```

GuardarScore.php

```
<?php
    include "bd.php";
    
    session_start();
     $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
        
        
     $puntos = $_POST['puntos'];
     $ejercicio = $_POST['ejercicio'];
     $entrenamiento = $_POST['entrenamiento'];
        

     $query = "INSERT INTO score (puntos, ejercicio,id_entrenamiento, id_usuario) VALUES ('$puntos','$ejercicio','$entrenamiento','$id')";
     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        
     if ($resultado === TRUE){
         echo "guardado";
     }else{
         echo "error";
     }
    

?>
```

nota 1: db.php es de donde viene la conexión a la base de datos.

nota 2: la variable de conección es la llamada conexion.

nota 3: si bien se que el error es que las variables no están definidas, por lo que entiendo (corríjanme si estoy mal) ahí la variable ya está definida.

Comment: No es necesario enviar la variable de sesión de una página a otra, para eso existen las sesiones, hacen eso por ti. Tu error es que no estás recuperando el valor de la variable de sesión, sino borrándolo. MIra mi respuesta al respecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En GuardarScore.php estás volviendo a asignar la variable de sesión id, en vez de recuperarla. De forma que la estás dejando vacía, porque en ese punto $id no está definida y por lo tanto es null.

Después, utilizas $id (que no tiene valor) en la consulta SQL de inserción.

Para recuperar el valor guardado en sesión para id, tienes que hacerlo así:

**GuardarScore.php**

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

//Mal: $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Comment: ooo si tenias razón muchas gracias, pero ahora me dice que el índex no está definido. Tengo la teoría de que es porque la forma en que el Android llama a las paginas hace que la session en login se cierre y en guardarscore se inicie una nueva o no? o ahí que podría ser?

Comment: Depende de cómo lo hagas desde la app, si lo que haces son llamadas totalmente independientes, entonces cada una es una sesión nueva, y eso encajaría con el error de undefined index 'id' en $_SESSION.

Comment: Aaaaah entonces ese es mi problema, gracias

Answer (score -1):

No es necesario que tengas la linea de `sesion_start();` por que ya tienes incluido la sesion de php en la pagina

```
include "bd.php";
```

Lo que puedes hacer es un echo de las variables de sesion que crea

por ejemplo esto

```
<? $primera = $_SESSION['id'] ?>
```

y para renombrarla o darle un valor
podrias hacer esto

```
<?php $h = 1; $respuesta = $_SESSION['id'] = $h; echo $respuesta
```

Checalo a ver que te parece y me comentas

Comment: Como le dije al usuario de arriba, ahora me tira que el index no está definido, por lo que no puedo hacer lo que me sugieres.